# django language translation

Tags: django

hiii 
i have this statement.I want to translate the info message what should i do.Its under HttpResponseRedirect..
return HttpResponseRedirect('/Info?info=You have not logged in yet')..

i want to translate to German You have not logged in yet to german stuff.I knw i have to update the po files..

but if use *('/Info?info=You have not logged in yet')::::error
 if i use  ('/Info?info=*(You have not logged in yet')) ::::error .
please help!!!!!!
Thanks in advance

Comment: What kind of error you get? Also, you do know that for urls you can only use alphanumerics [0-9a-zA-Z], the special characters "$-_.+!*'()," [not including the quotes], and reserved characters (it can be a problem with some german letters)?

Comment: It gives me Page Not found error and translate the whole message  and shows at the address bar

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to use a string builder to format it:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _
return HttpResponseRedirect('/Info?info=%s' % (_('You have not logged in yet'),))
```